# Normalizing impact of outnumbered positive reviews to extract sentiment of each term

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to extract the sentiment of Italian words using reviews that users wrote on Italian amazon. After doing some cleaning (remove punctuation, stop-words, etc.) I used this method to get the sentiment:

```
s = (tf_1/tf)*(-2) + (tf_2/tf)*(-1) + (tf_4/tf)*(1) + (tf_5/tf)*(2)
```

Where *tf* is the term frequency in the whole corpus of reviews, *tf_1* is the term frequency in one-star reviews and the like. But the problem is that, overall, most reviews are 4 and 5 stars (more than 80%). So a lot of neutral words end up with positive sentiments. How can I normalize this effect? I tried the following method, but the result got worse:

```
s = ((tf_1/n1)*(-2) + (tf_2/n2)*(-1) + (tf_4/n4)*(1) + (tf_5/n5)*(2)) * (n/tf)
```

Where *n* is the number of total reviews, *n1* is the number of reviews with one star and the like.